# Passing array data from Swift to React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on a `react-native` plugin and am not sure why my collection data is not passing through.

This is my swift code:

```
    @objc(getItems:rejecter:)
    func getItems:rejecter(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
        return resolve(itemManager.items)
    }
```

where `itemManager.items` is an array with this structure `[[ name = Meh 1, primary : Yes ], [ name = Meh 2, primary : No ]]`

Calling this from JavaScript I get an array with the correct number of items, but they are `null` instead of the actual json objects I was expecting.

Can anyone please advise on how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that custom classes or structures can't be automatically translated into JSON, so first you'll need to parse each one of your items into a NSDictionary, using each of those props as a dictionary key.

```
  @objc(getItems:rejecter:)
  func getItems:rejecter(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    let result: NSMutableArray = []
    for item in items {
      let yourAuxDic: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
      yourAuxDic["name"] = item.name
      yourAuxDic["primary"] = item.primary
      result.add(yourAuxDic)
    }
    resolve(result)
  }
```

Hope that helps!